# Is it a bad sign that an ipad app runs perfectly on the ipad but not in the simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i've been developing an ipad app for quite some time now, all the previous versions run perfectly on both the simulator and the Ipad, but the newest version which is a major revamp of the app, runs super smooth on the ipad but has a lot of issues on the simulator (images not appearing, etc)

Is this a bad sign? Should i wait to make it work on both before submitting?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done something trivial, like have you got the emulator running at an earlier API level than your App?

Comment: What iOS versions are you using on the device and simulator? Are they different?

Comment: I think it would be very important to understand _why_ it's not working in the simulator. It's not that you should be concerned about your app working well in a simulator, it's that you want to rule out the chance of it happening on real devices.

Comment: @diagonalbatman: I don't think so, but will check that out just in case.
@Robert: 4.3.2 on both, but i want to target to 3.0+ after fixing this issue
@magma: yeah i'm checking that right now :S but can't find what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you be sure to test it on both versions of iPad and as many OS versions as you can.  Be sure that you are running the same OS on both simulator and iPad (As I see in the comments that you say you are).  Just to rule out any problems with using code that is incompatable with older OS's.

In general though, if your app is running fine on the hardware you shouldn't have anything to worry about.  I would be much more concerned if it was the other way around.

Comment: Unless it the simulator which is following the OS specifications to the letter, and the hardware is more accomodating and tolerates some non-standard behaviour of the app.

Comment: Well at the end of the day its the hardware you are running on and since its apple you know every iPad is the same aside from OS version.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost always bad when an app does something you did not expect or design it to do.  If you designed the app to run on both the Simulator and the iPad, and it doesn't run on  one, there is possibly something seriously wrong with your design that could do other unknown things during app review, or worse, on many app user's devices (leading to lots of 1-star ratings).

Therefore you should figure out why something is going wrong, and preferably fix it (or at least understand what's happening well enough to determine how it will behave on your customer's iPads).

Answer (score 0):

Some other suggestions:

- make sure that both device and simulator are using the same internet connection
- uninstall your app from simulator and device, and run clean on your project, and then do a fresh install